# помогите разобраться с мультипоточностью Python

Tags: python, многопоточность

Вопрос банальный но что-то я уперся в стену непонимания.
есть 2 функции условно f1 и f2
все примеры показывают как запихнуть в параллельные потоки f1.
мне же нужно чтобы параллельно выполнялись f1 и f2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Две функции выполняются одновременно:

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def f1():
    while True:
        print('f1')
        time.sleep(1)

def f2():
    while True:
        print('f2')
        time.sleep(1)

thread_1 = Thread(target=f1)
thread_1.start()

thread_2 = Thread(target=f2)
thread_2.start()
```

Comment: СПАСИБО. а то что-то клин у мну был. или умных книжек перечитал )))